# How many levels of categories is possible in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress allows to have categories and sub categories.

But how long can I go in category levels?

I mean:

CAT1 -> subcat1 -> subsubcat1 -> subsubsubcat1....etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress said 5 to 15:
--> "However, you don’t want irrelevant content showing up on the topics listings or search, and neither do we. That’s why we limit the number of tags and categories that can be used on a public topic listing. Five to 15 tags (or categories, or a combination of the two) is a good number to add to each of your posts. The more categories you use, the less likely it is that your post will be selected for inclusion in the topics listings" ---> https://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/categories/

ps:
from the point of view of SEO 15 are not to be recommended